# Electrical noise between dimmer circuit and halogen transformer output

Tags: noise, emc, esp32, dimmer, touch

I am currently building an ESP32-based dimmer control for halogen transformers.

The dimmer should be controlled by touching any part of the transformer output circuit. Thus, I somehow need to connect the transformer output with the dimmer circuit and detect touches using the ESP32.

I utilized a BC516 darlington PNP transistor to sense touches and connected the base towards the outer part of the lamp case (which will be touched later), in order to create a voltage drop from lamp to earth.

Dimming using phase angle control with a BTA16 TRIAC as well as touch sensing work just fine - until I connect the sense pin to any side of the halogen transformer output. Depending on which direction I plugged in the mains connector, I get either noise or my readings just drop to GND and touch information is completely lost.

Today I did some measurements and found out that voltage between earth (although transformer itself is only connected to N/L) and either transformer output is 230 VAC / 5-10 VAC (depending on plug direction). Short circuit current is roughly 0.5-2 mA, depending on the phase angle. How can this be? I assumed my transformer (OSRAM Halotec 225/230-240) offers galvanic isolation between input and output. But somehow I must have been wrong; otherwise, why is there current flowing?

I think that this will also induce the noise in my circuit. Mains voltage on my board is completely isolated using optocouplers.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNNujo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you have any questions let me know; I am a beginner regarding electromagnetic interference and noise in general, so this is in fact all I can tell you.

Comment: touch sensing is *all about* electromagnetic "interference" as you detect the changes in the "interference" caused by someone touching the thing. Clearly the "interference" changes when you connect it to a lightbulb circuit. you might want to get an oscilloscope and see if there's any detectable difference in the signal when it's touched or not touched. By the way, this transformer secondary is fully insulated from the primary, right? you don't want to get shocked.

Comment: What is a halogen transformer?

Comment: @user253751 You are right, I will probably need to dive a big deeper

Comment: @Andyaka A mains transformer for halogen bulbs (usually AC to AC)

Comment: “ otherwise, why is there current flowing?”… Because you placed a current meter across the barrier.

Comment: @RussellH What sould this tell me? The question is WHY there is a current flowing between secondary side and earth even though they are isolated. Or have I misunderstood your comment? I expected that there should be no current flow.

Comment: @Ercksen: when you place your ammeter from the secondary side to earth, they’re no longer isolated. They are connected by the low resistance of the ammeter.

Comment: Post your schematic, it can only help. Since you tried several post the most recent design. Be sure to annotate it.

Comment: @Ercksen Are you thinking of fluorescent bulbs? Halogen bulbs don't need a transformer. (Incidentally, transformers are *always* AC to AC; no transformer can input or output DC.)

Comment: Its a 230 VAC to 12 VAC transformer, so I definitely need it. By saying AC to AC transformer I mean, that there is no rectifier at its outout.